# V-model using v-for and manipulating array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can’t figure out in this case how manipulate with v-model change amounts array.

With this code i generated inputs for each item and i want with this inputs change amounts for each item in array eg: if write first input 10 first item amounts array will be 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10

I tried to make dynamic v-model prop with index but its not worked.

here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/532119/ can someone help me?

```
category: [{
            id: 0,
            sub: 'a1',
            types: [{
                    id: 1,
                    value: "P A",
                    amounts: [20, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    value: "P B",
                    amounts: [0, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    value: "P C",
                    amounts: [30, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    value: "P D",
                    amounts: [50, 32, 12, 30, 12, 2]
                }
            ]
        }]



<div id="app">

<div v-for="item in category">
    <h1>
        {{item.sub}}
    </h1>
    <div v-for="type in item.types"> 
        {{type.value}}  
        <input type="text" v-model="someModel">
         <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="amount in type.amounts">{{amount}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never want to `v-model` a value that you have not defined.

In this case, you don't need to v-model anything, you just want to respond to `change` events and call a method to reset the amounts.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      category: [
      {
                id: 0,
                sub: 'a1',
                types: [{
                        id: 1,
                        value: "P A",
                        amounts: [20, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        value: "P B",
                        amounts: [0, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        value: "P C",
                        amounts: [30, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        value: "P D",
                        amounts: [50, 32, 12, 30, 12, 2]
                    }
                ]
            },
             {
                id: 0,
                sub: 'a2',
                types: [{
                        id: 1,
                        value: "P A",
                        amounts: [20, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        value: "P B",
                        amounts: [0, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        value: "P C",
                        amounts: [30, 32, 20, 12, 12, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        value: "P D",
                        amounts: [50, 32, 12, 30, 12, 2]
                    }
                ]
            }]

  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    },
    setAllAmounts(type, event) {
     type.amounts = type.amounts.map((_) => event.target.value);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div v-for="item in category">
    <h1>
      {{item.sub}}
    </h1>
    <div v-for="type in item.types">
      {{type.value}}
      <input type="text" @change="setAllAmounts(type, $event)">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="amount in type.amounts">{{amount}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: You might want to change `@change` to `@input` to better mimick v-model behaviour.